# Can I tell a Ruby method to expect a specific parameter type?

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters

```
def doSomething(value)
    if (value.is_a?(Integer))
        print value * 2
    else
        print "Error: Expected integer value"
        exit
    end
end
```

Can I tell a Ruby method that a certain parameter *should* be an Integer, otherwise crash? Like Java.

Comment: Take a look at http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/046-issue-14-duck-typing.html. It explains what's known as "duck typing" and what we see as advantages to it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, you can't. You can only do what you're already doing: check the type yourself.

Comment: @Omega Generally there's no reason to restrict yourself to certain types. If the given type supports the operations you're trying to perform on it (in this case: if it can be multiplied by 2), restricting the method to only one type would decrease its flexibility (like: why shouldn't the user be able to use your method to double floating point values or complex numbers?). And if the type doesn't support the operation, you'll get an error anyway.

Comment: I though that if Ruby had this feature, when you're writing a Ruby program with a good IDE, the IDE would be able to "warn you" saying "hold on, you're about to pass an unsupported value to this method and you will be in trouble", like with Java lol. But aside from that, yeah you're right, I'll get an error anyway XD.

Comment: By the way, if this is the case, is Java the one with a "flaw"? Or am I talking about two very different worlds I shouldn't be comparing at all?

Comment: @Omega Java is something very different in that type errors in Java are compile-time errors, not runtime errors. So in Java the method wouldn't crash when given something other than an integer - it wouldn't compile in the first place. This is called static typing. Ruby isn't statically typed for a lot of reasons - including succinctness and flexibility. Adding type annotations to Ruby and adding static typing would be two different pairs of shoes. Static typing is impossible to combine with some of Ruby's features (like being able to define methods at runtime).

Comment: @sepp2k Cases where method accepts multiple types are very rare, in the most cases method relies on exact type or interface. Not having types is actually a bit of a pain when code grows, you don't know what type methods require, and need to look in docs every time, if docs don't exists then even look into code just to figure out what type a method requires.

Answer (score 11):

I'm late to the party, but I wanted to add something else:

A really important concept in Ruby is [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). The idea behind this principle is that you don't really care about the types of your variables, as far as they can do what you want to do with them. What you want in your method is to accept a variable that responds to (*). You don't care about the class name as far as the instance can be multiplied.

Because of that, in Ruby you will see more often the method `#responds_to?` than `#is_a?`

In general, you will be doing type assertion only when accepting values from external sources, such as user input.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest a raise unless type match at the beginning of the method

```
def do_something(value)
  raise TypeError, 'do_something expects an integer' unless value.kind_of?(Integer)
  ...
end
```

This is raise an error and exit unless value is an `Integer`

Answer (score 2):

You can raise an Exception anytime arbitrarily if you deem it necessary.

```
def doSomething(value)
    if (value.is_a?(Integer))
        print value * 2
    else
        raise "Expected integer value"
    end
end
```

Whether or not you *really* want to do this is a separate issue. :)

Comment: You can make it cleaner like this:

def doSomething(value); raise "Expected integer value" unless value.is_a? Integer;print value*2;end

Comment: I believe it would be more precise to raise `ArgumentError` than a simple `RuntimeError`.

Comment: Can you imagine doing this for every parameter on every method?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't have parameter type verification, though you can add sugar method to all objects for convenience to verify type like this:

```rb
def doSomething(value)
   print value.should_be(Numeric) * 2
end
```

or

```rb
def initialize(fruit)
   @fruit = fruit.should_be(Fruit)
end
```

```rb
Object.class_eval do

  def should_be cls
    hide_from_stack = true
    if self && !self.is_a?(cls)
      raise("Expected class #{cls}, got #{self.class}")
    end
    self
  end

end
```

Comment: It is also possible to add type signatures to Ruby methods using [RBS](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-rbs-type-annotation/).