# Knowing default parameter value

Tags: ruby

I have a method definition like this:

```
def m1(a:Int, b:String, c:Val)                                                 
end

m = method(:m1)
```

Note that `Int`, `String`, `Val` are default values for `a`, `b`, `c`.

Is it possible to get this information from the method object `m`?

Comment: this topic may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622324/getting-argument-names-in-ruby-reflection

I tried by myself to get those values following Method(http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-parameters) doc, but only what I got is whether argument is required or optional.

Comment: Do you want to get the types (classes) of the parameters in ruby? parameters cannot be bound to a type. More information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575581/can-i-tell-a-ruby-method-to-expect-a-specific-parameter-type

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. It has been discussed numerous times on the ruby-core mailinglist, but it's simply not feasible. What should your proposed method return for something like this:

```
def m(p: if rand < 0.5 then Time.now else ENV['HOME'] end) end
```